# CSS !important rule with list values

Tags: css

How do I specify a CSS rule as *!important*, where a value is comma separated list (like can be for *background*, *box-shadow* or *text-shadow*). Do I put the *!important* mark separately for each list item or only after the last item?

Summing it up, do I write

```
background: url(image1.png) no-repeat 0 1px,
            url(image2.png) no-repeat 0 2px !important;
```

or

```
background: url(image1.png) no-repeat 0 1px !important,
            url(image2.png) no-repeat 0 2px !important;
```

Comment: Why would you need to use `!important` in those declarations?

Comment: Well, what have you tried ?

Comment: It's `!important`. Not `important!`. There's only one valid place to put the `!`.

Comment: You should be able to figure this out yourself quite easily shouldn't you?  More importantly, why would you not resort to using a more specific selector instead of resorting to sloppy / bad practice?

Comment: I know it's a bad practice, but I need those !importants to apply custom styling to a GWT generated code. Not only GWT uses inline HTML element styling a lot, but also adds *!important* in many places too. I would do it the other way if starting from scratch, but it's just a task I've been assigned at work.

Comment: And I asked the question mostly out of curiosity.

Comment: The question seems pretty simple and straightforward and anyone with basic CSS knowledge would be able to understand it. I'm not sure why 4 people voted to close this as unclear, but the votes don't sit well with me so I'm going to override them with a custom close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the `!important` at the end, prior to the closing semi-colon.

Note that it works to override the property value as a whole, not individual components of it- so it cannot be applied to the individual comma separated arguments (indeed, this would be a pointless exercise as you'd logically only then need a single argument, the one you are making important).

That said, note as [per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), the use of `!important` is not recommended:

> The !important exception
>
> When an !important rule is used on a style declaration, this
>   declaration overrides any other declaration made in the CSS, wherever
>   it is in the declaration list. Although, !important has nothing to do
>   with specificity.  Using !important is bad practice because it makes
>   debugging hard since you break the natural cascading in your
>   stylesheets.
>
> Some rules of thumb
>
> 1. Never use !important on site-wide css.
> 2. Only use !important on
>      page-specific css that overrides site-wide or foreign css (from ExtJs
>      or YUI for example).
> 3. Never use !important when you're writing a
>      plugin/mashup.
> 4. Always look for a way to use specificity before even
>      considering !important

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put `!important` at the end of each line that you would like to apply this rule too. So, to answer your question your second example is how you would do it.

However using `!important` is not recommended, it creates sloppy poorly thought out code, makes it less maintainable, and overrides styles declared in user style sheets, thus degrading accessibility.